# Como aplicar hash al archivo pdf generado con mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

Espero se encuentren todos bien en esta querida comunidad.
En base a un form en html, genero un documento y le tengo que dar protección con un hash256 (no me sirve lo de generar una password). Hasta generar el PDF no tengo problema. Entiendo que la función hash_file('sha256',$archivo) es la que me permite hacer el hash (de hecho la he probado por fuera y funciona).
mPDF permite ver el PDF que se genera o directamente bajarlo, para cualquiera de las 2 opciones necesito aplicarle el hash antes que ocurra cualquiera de las 2 opciones.
Hasta el momento he probado:

```
    try {
        $mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4');
        $mpdf->debug = true;
        $mpdf -> SetTitle('Solicitud de préstamo '.$nombre.'');
        $css = file_get_contents('css/estiloPrestamo.css');
        $mpdf->writeHTML($css, 1);
        $mpdf->writeHTML($html);
//$validador = hash_file('sha256',$html);
//$validador = hash_file('sha256',$mpdf);
//$mpdf->Output('../../pdf_inscr/'.$codInscrip.'.pdf', 'F');
        $mpdf->hash_file('sha256',Output('../../pdf_inscr/'.$codInscrip, 'F'));
    } catch (MpdfException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
      echo $validador;
```

Sin lo que está comentado y el echo $validador, el pdf se genera perfectamente.
La versión de mPDF es la Version:  6.1

Quedo a disposición por si fuera necesario algún otro dato o sugerencias.

Comment: Gracias F.Igor. Había visto eso en la documentación. Pero me habían encargado especialmente que fuera sha256. Voy a esperar un par de días y si no hay nadie más que tenga una sugerencia te la marcó como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

SI lo que buscas es proteger el documento (sin necesidad de contraseña, pero restringiendo la modificacion de este, por ejemplo) es aplicar el metodo `SetProtection(permissions, user, pass, enc_length)`:

```
$mpdf->SetProtection(array('modify'),null,null,128);
// ...
$mpdf->Output('../../pdf_inscr/'.$codInscrip.'.pdf', 'F');
```

En este caso, protegido para modificacion, sin password y encriptado 128-bit.

Ver documentacion en https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setprotection.html